# find nouser equivalent for POSIX ACLs

Tags: access-control-list, posix

On a Linux system it is possible to find files that are owned by a uid that does not have a user name assigned with "find -nouser".  I have been looking for an equivalent that will search the POSIX ACL lists for non-existent users, but have had no luck.  Does anyone know of a method or utility to do this?

Comment: If find -exec getfacl results in an output distinctive to non-existent users (like a number instead of the user name), the results could be piped into a regular expression searching for this pattern. I would try it but I'm not about to create non-existent users just to find out.

Comment: Something like:    find . -name '*.ext' -exec getfacl {} \; | grep "owner: [0-9]"        If that works I'll make it an answer. :)

Comment: Using grep on the output of getfacl doesn't actually return the file name.  It only returns the line with the uid instead of the name.

Comment: More on that grep "owner: " line.  The "owner: " section of getfacl is the same as the owner find will see.  I need to match the "user: " lines.

Comment: On my Linux system, "user:" lines show permissions like "rwx". The following can be used to combine lines (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545538/how-do-i-join-pairs-of-consecutive-lines-in-a-large-file-1-million-lines-using): find . -name '*.jpg' -exec getfacl {} \; | egrep 'file|owner' | sed -rn 'N;s/\n/ /;p'

Comment: You can substitute another data line for owner in the egrep argument if you like.

Comment: OK, this sed command combines every other line.  If I have multiple users in the ACL it will stil return multiple lines.  In the end what I want is to return the information in the "file:" line if the information in the "user:" line is numeric.

Comment: Sorry, I have no ACL filesystems to work with at the moment so no output to practice with...